# How to set Visible false to one of column in Lookup Edit on RibbonControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, ribbon-control, repositorylookupedit

I attached Data Source to Lookup Edit (BarEditItem) on Ribbon Control. Now I need to hide one column in that, How do I set the Visible property to False? In normal form Lookup Edit, just select control and populate all columns and set false to what I don't need to show. How do I do this in Ribbon Control BarEditItem?

[image: Lookup Edit (BarEditItem)]

I attached image please please refer it. Lookup Edit(BarEditItem) on Ribbon Control.

Comment: Have you tried to access the repositoryItem inside the BarEditItem? Hope there is a property. Else let me know i will check on Monday dont have DevExpress at home :(

Comment: No cont access in Ribbon Control instead of repositoryLookupEdit BarEditItem is available in Ribbon Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select your `BarEditItem` on the ribbon control
2. Go to the **Properties** panel, and open the Edit element
3. Go to the **Columns** element.
4. Set the `Visible` property of the column you want to hide to `False`